# Connect to Multiple Redis Instance using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, servicestack

I have multiple redis instances on my host (ports 6379, 6380). Currently I'm able to connect to the first instance (6379) using the setup below:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRedisClientsManager>(p =>
               new PooledRedisClientManager(Configuration.GetValue<long>("Redis:DatabaseId"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("127.0.0.1:6379"))
               {
                   ConnectTimeout = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Redis:connectTimeOut"),
                   IdleTimeOutSecs = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Redis:idleTimeOutSecs"),
                   PoolTimeout = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Redis:poolTimeOut")
               });
```

Given past experiences with Single Redis instance or Redis sentinel, i have decided to split mutually exclusive operations across multiple Redis instances to spread the work load

for example:

All Operation A will use the 6379 instance while
All Operation B will use the 6380 instance

I have read ServiceStack documentation but didn't find any relevant information.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've configured your [PooledRedisClientManager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#pooledredisclientmanager) with both primary and replica servers, when you resolve a read/write client, i.e:

```
using var redis = clientsManager.GetClient();
```

It will resolve the client connected to the primary server, whilst when resolving a readonly client:

```
using var redisReadOnly = clientsManager.GetReadOnlyClient();
```

It will resolve a client connected to one of the replicas instead.

Comment: Hi mythz, Thanks for the contribution. The redis instances are standalone and not replicas. The idea is to persist different operations to different instances using servicestack

Comment: You wont be able to do that with the same `PooledRedisClientManager` instance, you can try registering a 2nd instance in the IOC against the concrete `PooledRedisClientManager` Type that way the default `IRedisClientsManager` resolves the first instance whilst `PooledRedisClientManager` resolves the second pool, otherwise you can create a new `RedisClient(host)` instance when you need it without using a pool, if the redis servers are on the same server (i.e. 127.0.0.1) there's no benefit to using a Pooled client manager.